# Is there a way to take output like this?

Tags: python

For some x^n, find the sum of its digits until there is only a one digit. The order of commandline arguments:
python3 file.py a b => python file.py 2 5
Output : 2ˆ5 = 32 = 3 + 2 = 5

My output should be like this above but when ı run the code below it gives a output like for a = 2 b = 8
it gives:
2 ^ 8 = 256 = 2 + 5 + 6 + 13 = 2 ^ 8 = 13 = 1 + 3 + 4

Is there a way my code to give output like in the first?

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

n = (int(a) ** int(b))

total = 0

if n < 10:
    print(f"{str(a)} ^ {str(b)} = {str(n)}")

list1 = [n]


def sum_of_digits():
    global total
    global n
    while n >= 10:
        print(f"{str(a)} ^ {str(b)} = {str(n)}", end=' = ')
        for m in str(list1[0]):
            total += int(m)
            print(m, end=" + ")
        list1.insert(0, total)
        n = total
        print(total, end=" = ")
        total = 0
    return n
```

Comment: Try to think more clearly about your logic. In particular, write down each step of how you want the program to proceed, in plain English words, and then check the code against that specfication. It's especially important here that you are able to explain why you use `end=' = '` in your `print` calls, and explain what you expect that to do and why it is a good idea, in which situations.

Comment: Avoid globals, as much as possible.  The preferred  mechanism of communication between the main program and its functions is via input arguments and returned values.  Try this:  `a = 20; b = 17; print(sum([int(c) for c in str(a**b)]))` and try to understand what happens.

Comment: what is the use of `list1`, have you tried a debugger or print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

def sum_of_digits(a, b):
    # Use casts as we can't guarantee the input data type
    n = int(a)**int(b)
    res_list = [str(a), '^', str(b), ' = ', str(n)]
    while len([x for x in str(n)]) > 1:
        current = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
        n = sum(current)
        res_list.append(' = ')
        res_list.extend(' + '.join(str(x) for x in current))
        res_list.append(' = ')
        res_list.extend([x for x in str(n)])
    print(''.join(res_list))

sum_of_digits(a, b)
```

```
>>> sum_of_digits('2', '8')
2^8 = 256 = 2 + 5 + 6 = 13 = 1 + 3 = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

#### recursive function to call `a` to the power of `b`

```
def pow(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1

    elif b == 1:
        return a

    else:
        return a * pow(a, b-1)

def findsum(val):
    if val < 10:
        return val

    else:
        return (val%10) + findsum(int(val/10))
```

now write `def sum_of_digits()` function that call `pow` function with arguments `a`, `b`:

```
def sum_of_digits(a, b):
    val = pow(a, b)

    return(findsum(val))
```

Save above functions in test.py file

```
from test import *
sum_of_digits(2,10)
```

to get output of `7`

Comment: OP knows that he can write `a**b`, so the first part of your answer is totally unwarranted.  Also you have an home-made version of integer division, that in Python2 is just `n/10` while in Python3 it's `n//10`

Comment: never call your files `test` it will give you big trouble someday and test might be a buildin module or function or shell command